# How to mount root to a directory in express?

Tags: node.js, express

I am trying to mount a particular directory in an app to root. The structure of my app is

```
/app
  /server.js
  /views
    /statics
        /index.html
    /partials
  /public
    /javascript
    /css
    /images
```

I want the static to be served as root so I can access index.html at localhostL:4001/index.html instead of localhostL:4001/static/views/index/html

I have tried to use express.statics. However, it didn't work.

in server.js

```
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use('/', express.static('views/statics'));
```

Comment: why not serve as `app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index'))` after mounting the view middleware? That way your html will be served at localhost:4001

Comment: I think that by using     app.use('/', express.static('views/statics')); the .    app.get('/', (req, res) => res.sendFile('index')) is already included, no?

Comment: you can use 'view engine' to parse and render 'html', that way you don't have to access 'html' files as, localhostL:4001/static/views/index/html

Comment: Are there any other ways you can do without using ' view engine'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be `app.use('/', express.static('views/statics'));`
check the working model here : https://repl.it/@VikashSingh1/SlategrayDeadRobot

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are using relative path to serve static files instead of this you can use absolute path for serving files like this

```
app.use(express.statics(path.join(__dirname, 'views/statics'));
```

This will solve your problem.